# Restrain page access to one user at the time

Tags: java, php, jquery, ajax

I have two user: X and Y. And one page: Page Z. To access page Z I have a link.

If page Z is already open in user X browser I want the link to be disabled and denied the access to the page to user Y.

- How can I do that?
- Which language is the most apropriate to do that (jQuery, Php, etc)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This will be difficult to enforse. Javascript etc can be disabled at client side

Comment: I have a document that is common to several users. All of them can modified it. I can't allow two users to modifie the same document at the same time or one of them will be overwrite when saved.

Comment: I would say this would be borderline impossible to set up a 'workable' solution in HTTP as HTTP is stateless. How are you going to deal with a situation where a user has said page open for hours or just straight closes the browser?

Comment: @user1788758 your requirement is different. Your actual question is how can I write lock a document. And I believe the answer will depend on where the document is stored (db or file system).

Comment: If you are using a database. The engine within it should prevent two users writing to the same record by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not listen to any of these answers.

you can do this(although it is true that its kind of awkward)

you need PHP javascript (use j-query) and mysql. Your going to want to create a php script that gives the first user on a variable session, and every couple seconds or so your ajax will keep sending the db a script with php time(); when the second user comes on the php page will ask the db if there are any refreshes within 4 seconds, meaning that if the first user is still logged on there will be no more than a three second delay from the db time. and if there isn't  that means the user is idle or has gone off the page and you can allow access. to redirect with php you can user the header function. If you are interested in EXACTLY how to do this upgrade my response and reply because it is pretty long and i do not want to write it for no reason.

```
this is the page you want people to go on:
 $times = time(); 
 $num = $times + 10000;
mysql_connect("localhost", "dbname", "password") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  FROM $tablename WHERE areloggedin > $num);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
if( $num < 0 ){
header('Location: http://redirectpage.html');
```

}else{

```
   $times = time(); 
     $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
                if (!$con)
                {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                 } 
                mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);


                $qry = mysql_query("UPDATE
                                     $tbalename SET      
                                    `areloggedin`= '$times'
                WHERE id = $variable_seession_foruser ");


                $result = @mysql_query($qry);
```

}

?>

(your html)

function ok(){

    $.get("php/foo.php"  ,                   function(data) {

        });


setIntreval(ok,3000);

//sepearate php file named foo.php

Comment: give me a few hours Ill give you the complete code as a comment

Comment: your welcome, I actually use this for a p2p enviorment where I need a maximum of two on at a time, otherwise it has a redirect,and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

What you can is that create a boolean variable on server side and track it. When user if page Z is accessed by someone then set this variable true and while someone else is trying to open that link then check if boolean variable is true then stop them to redirect to that page and if it is false then take them to page Z. Once user left the page then set boolean variable to false.

**This could be one way to achieve it but still I do not think that it is that straight forward. You will face many obstacles while implementing it.**

Comment: How are you going to track if a user has left the page? if I open a page on a site and then navigate away from the page by typing in a new URL no code would execute to write the variable to allow other users to access the link.

Comment: Read the bold text again if you missed it. BTW it could be tracked using `window.onbeforeunload`

Answer (score 0):

just trying to come up with a quick implementation/workaround for something like this:

#### What you need

1. System-wide cache, (APC or SESSIONS **won't do**). You need something like [memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) or [redis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis) so that multiple threads can access the same cache.
2. OR just a database+crontabs I guess (but cache is preferred)
3. PHP/Server-side scripting
4. Javscript-enabled clients

#### Strategy

1. Javascript makes an HTTP request every X (TTL) seconds. This request sets the key 'occupied' (in your chosen cache) to the clients IP with a cache-ttl of X+5 seconds. (If you opt for DB you'll need a cronjob reseting the entry every X seconds)
2. If a user tries to access the page and the 'key' !== their IP address, deny access.

#### Caveats

1. ONLY allow users to edit if they have JS enabled, display warning otherwise
2. Puts the trust in your users, they can bypass this easily.

#### Summary

Basically described an artificial keep-alive session using JS + cache, you can set the TTL to as long or as short as you want, depending on how actively the page is going to be edited.

Comment: @user1610582 I don't see why he shouldn't 'listen' to this, since we're both describing pretty much the same thing.